# flutter CertificateException video player issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

i'm using the dart package video_player 2.4.5 to play videos in my app, in ios it works perfectly but in android it isn't due to an https error, because when i replace https link with an http link it works.

my code :
`VideoPlayerController.network('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4')..initialize().then((_) {setState(() {});`

error :
`java.security.cert.CertificateException`

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to skirt that error is to replace the https links by http in initState like that :

`if (Platform.isAndroid) {url = widget.newsFeed.mediaUrl.toString().replaceAll('https', 'http');} else if(Platform.isIOS) {url = widget.newsFeed.mediaUrl.toString();} _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(url)..initialize().then((_) {setState(() {});});`

Comment: The best way should still be not to do that and use the https and just bypass the error. because what if the https works again?